# Terminating while loop with a return from input prompt - Python

Tags: python, loops

In my program, I want to be able to call a function while the answer to the prompt, "Another go?", is "Yes" or "yes", and to stop when the answer to the prompt is anything else.

This is my code:

```
``
prompt = ""
def my_function():
    prompt = input("Another go?")

my_function()
while prompt == "yes" or "Yes":
    my_function()
```

With the program above, the program repeatedly returns the prompt, "Another go?", the first time the program is run. However the program isn't terminated when an answer other than "yes" or "Yes"  given, and so continues to return the prompt regardless of my answer. Furthermore, when you run the program for the second or third time by running the program once more, the prompt is only returned once along with the answer you gave the first time you ran the program.

I want the program to repeatedly return the prompt in the second and third times I run the program and I want the program to terminate the while loop when an answer other than "yes" or "Yes" is given.

If someone can please share their expertise on this problem, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
def my_function():
    return input("Another go?")


prompt = my_function()
while prompt in ("yes", "Yes"):
    prompt  = my_function()
```

This code will exit the loop if the input value is not "Yes" or "yes" and will not enter the while if the first time that yes answer didn't input by the user.